# PHP, after setting an array in a method, how can I get it from a different method in same class

Tags: php, arrays, oop, laravel

I have a `class`, in this class I have a method that sets my array. 
How can I get values of this `array` and use them from another `method` in same `class`?

This my class:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    private $tmp = array();

    public function setValues(){

        array_push($this->tmp,"blue","yellow");

        print_r(array_values($this->tmp)); // It works well, I can see values.
    }


    public function getValues(){

       print_r(array_values($this->tmp)); // It doesn't work - shows empty array.

       // return $this->tmp also doesn't work - shows empty array.
    }

}
```

How can I get values of this array?

Comment: You have to call the function setValues() before call getValues(), or put in the __construct ...

Comment: It is probably not a singleton. So when you call the controller again you are calling on a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how controllers work in Laravel. However, if it is similar to other frameworks then the Controller is not a singleton. A new controller is potentially created for each request. This means that you are calling `setValues();` on one instance of the class and `getValues();` on another.

I am pretty sure you can configure Laravel to treat the Controller a singleton.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container Shows how you can register your controller as a singleton if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It works! You need to call setter first, and then getter:

```
$o = new HomeController();
$o->setValues();
$o->getValues();
```

Check yourself again, please: https://ideone.com/UYAfxe

Comment: I have two buttons (and 2 requests) first button calls setvalues method , second button calls getvalues method. Should i call them in one request ?